# React-Bootstrap NavDropDown is background color not filling full dropdown menu, it leaves top & bottom as whilte

Tags: reactjs, bootstrap-4, react-navigation, navbar, react-bootstrap

I am trying to change the background color of the dropdown div in react-bootstrap but the top & bottom part of the dropdown menu is still appearing in white(refer image).
I tried custom css but it didn't work. Any help will be of great help
Codepen link: https://codepen.io/vishalprasad2020/pen/QWjvQqd

[image: React-Bootstrap NavDropdown background color issue]

```js
const {
  Navbar,
  Nav,
  NavItem,
  NavDropdown,
  MenuItem
} = ReactBootstrap;

class NavbarInstance extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Navbar id="basic-nav-dropdown1">
        <Navbar.Header>
          <Navbar.Brand>
            <a href="#">React-Bootstrap</a>
          </Navbar.Brand>
        </Navbar.Header>
        <Nav>
          <NavItem eventKey={1} href="#">Link</NavItem>
          <NavItem eventKey={2} href="#">Link</NavItem>
          <NavDropdown eventKey={3} title="Dropdown" id="basic-nav-dropdown">
            <MenuItem id="basic-nav-dropdown1" eventKey={3.1}>Action</MenuItem>
            <MenuItem id="basic-nav-dropdown1" eventKey={3.2}>Another action</MenuItem>
            <MenuItem id="basic-nav-dropdown1" eventKey={3.3}>Something else here</MenuItem>
            <MenuItem id="basic-nav-dropdown1" eventKey={3.3}>Separated link</MenuItem>
          </NavDropdown>
        </Nav>
      </Navbar>
    );
  }
}

class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <NavbarInstance></NavbarInstance>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.body);
```

```css
#basic-nav-dropdown{
  background-color:yellow;
}
#basic-nav-dropdown1{
  background-color:yellow;
}
body{
  background-color:yellow;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you add this to your css file, your problem will be solved.  I hope I could help.

```
   ul.dropdown-menu {
     padding: 0px 0px;
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
.dropdown-menu { background-color: yellow; }
```

[Demo](https://codepen.io/andrei-gheorghiu/pen/zYvwWVG)